# Trying to convert a Object in a generic T returns null

Tags: c#, json, .net, list, generics

I have this method

```cs
private T ConsumirServicioERP()
{
    ResponseERP responseERP = new ResponseERP();
    var unescaped = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string>(responseApi.Content);
    var defoBJ = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ResponseERP2>(unescaped);
    responseERP.code = defoBJ.code;
    responseERP.data = new List<dataERP>();
    responseERP.data.AddRange(defoBJ.data[0]);
    T someGeneric = responseERP as T;
    return someGeneric;
}
```

debugging the code, responseERP has data, but when I return someGeneric, it has null.
I tried to do:

```cs
return (T)Convert.ChangeType(responseERP, typeof(T));
```

but it throws a System.InvalidCastException: 'Object must implement IConvertible.'

Comment: ResponseERP is not of type T, so it cannot be converted - it will return null if you use "as T" and throw error if you use casting "(T)myVar", and throw error if you try to convert it too (like in your example).

Comment: What is `T`? Why do you think `ResponseERP` is convertible to `T`?

Comment: What is it you are actually trying to do? This smells like a possible miss use of generics, and that some other pattern will fit better. But without more details it is difficult to tell.

Comment: You might want to "map" that responseERP instead? Using custom mapping or maybe using AutoMapper or Mapster or some library like those?